# Chrome extension's popup user activation

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

#### Background

There are some Web APIs that are "[gated by user activation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#user-activation-gated-apis)". An example of such an API is the Fullscreen API.

#### Question

Default popup page window is not treated as being user activated. Why is that? I would expect that if a user **clicked** the toolbar icon to open the popup the code will be treated as user activated.

#### Example

`manifest.json`

```json
{
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Test"
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
    }

}
```

`popup.html`

```html
<html>
   <body>
       <script src="popup.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

`popup.js`

```js
document.body.requestFullscreen();
```

The above code won't work. In Chrome I will get following warning: `Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`

Answer (score 0):

this is not the best practice, but might be a workaround

1. when clicking popup, without opening the popup on the toolbar, use `chrome.action.onClick` to get the event and open the popup in the new tab, and run `document.body.requestFullscreen();`
2. when full screen exits, remove that tab

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. I placed following code inside `onClicked` handler: `await chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html') })`. Got again same warning: `Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`

Comment: yes, I tried as well, still has the `API can only be initiated by a user gesture.` error, seems it doesn't matter it is on popup or tab